# How to sort Table in gsp contaning sql rows passed by controller

Tags: javascript, grails, groovy, gsp

I am using sortablecolumn feature of Grails to dynamically sort the table columns in gsp. I have 3 table's containing sql rows passed by controller code.

My Controller code is:

```
def ABC{
def A= AService.a()
def B=BService.b()
def C=CService.b()
render(view:list,model:[A:A,B:B,C:C])
}
```

AService, BService, and CService contains sql code and returns the rows.

My list.gsp code is:

```
<body>
        <div class="body">
            <h1>ABC</h1>
            <g:if test="${flash.message}">
            <div class="message">${flash.message}</div>
            </g:if>
            <div class="list">
                <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <g:sortableColumn property="name" title="NAME" />
                        <g:sortableColumn property="id" title="ID" />


                        <th>&nbsp;</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <g:each in="${A}" status="i" var="thisRecord">
                    <tr class="${(i % 2) == 0 ? 'odd' : 'even'}">
                        <td>${thisRecord.name}</td>
                        <td>${thisRecord.id}</td>


                    </tr>
                </g:each>
                </tbody>
                </table>
                </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And two other tables. Whenever I click on the columns on front end the tables are not sorting correctly. Please correct me where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The sorting typically occurs server side. Thus the sort parameters are passed into the controller, and the query function takes the sort parameters to sort the data. The view layer does not do the sorting. Your controller is expected to return the sorted data. In your example, you would need to add code to sort the data before it is returned via the render method.